# manually creating an Symfony UploadedFile

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5

I'm facing following problem and can't seem to figure this one out.
I wrote an API endpoint accepting a POST with binary data (header: content-type:image/jpeg).

I know i can read out the raw string with `file_get_content('php://input')` or Laravel's `$request->getContent()`.
PHP also has a function `createimagefromstring($string)` which also seems to read the string in correctly.

What i'd like to do is create an UploadedFile from this raw data , so that I can handle it with already written functions.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 15):

I think I found it... Still curious if there are improvements that can be made..

```
$imgRaw = imagecreatefromstring( $request->getContent() );
if ($imgRaw !== false) {
    imagejpeg($imgRaw, storage_path().'/tmp/tmp.jpg',100);
    imagedestroy($imgRaw);
    $file =  new UploadedFile( storage_path().'/tmp/tmp.jpg', 'tmp.jpg', 'image/jpeg',null,null,true);
    // DO STUFF WITH THE UploadedFile
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use base64 encoding. Symfony have some nice stuff for this.

Your code will be smthng like this:

```
$base64Content = $request->request->get('base64Content'); // this is your post data
$yourFile = new UploadedBase64EncodedFile(new Base64EncodedFile($base64Content)); // this is an instance of UploadedFile
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I assume this is from https://github.com/hshn/base64-encoded-file? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't remember exactly if it's included by default.

Answer (score 5):

As per Laravel 8

Just follow the constructor:

```
     * @param string      $path         The full temporary path to the file
     * @param string      $originalName The original file name of the uploaded file
     * @param string|null $mimeType     The type of the file as provided by PHP; null defaults to application/octet-stream
     * @param int|null    $error        The error constant of the upload (one of PHP's UPLOAD_ERR_XXX constants); null defaults to UPLOAD_ERR_OK
     * @param bool        $test         Whether the test mode is active

    $file = new UploadedFile(
        $pathIncludingFilename, 
        $fileName, 
        'image/jpeg', 
        null, 
        false
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to manually create it, Symfony parses received $_FILES array for you. Http Request object has a FileBag property called $files with a get() method which returns an UploadedFile instance.

```
/** @var UploadedFile $file */
$file = $request->files->get('user-pictures-upload')[0];
$cmd = new UploadPictureCmd($file, $this->getUser()->getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of generating images files using `fzaninotto/faker` in Symfony 4 Fixtures

```
class FileFixtures extends Fixture
{
    private $faker;
    private $parameterBag;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag)
    {
        $this->faker = Factory::create();
        $this->parameterBag = $parameterBag;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {            
        $tempFixturesPath = $this->parameterBag->get('kernel.project_dir') . '/tmp';
        if (!file_exists($tempFixturesPath)) {
            mkdir($tempFixturesPath);
        }
        $fileName = $this->faker->image($tempFixturesPath, 640, 480, 'cats', false, true);
        $file = new UploadedFile($tempFixturesPath . '/' . $fileName, $fileName, 'image/jpeg', null, null, true);
        //do something with $file
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If it counts for anything, this is how I did it in Laravel 5.4. In my case, I wanted to be able to easily resize an image and be able to do something like this.

```
request()->file('image')->resize(250, 250)->store('path/to/storage');
```

This is what I did to the UploadedFile class.

Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile.php *~this file ships with the Laravel framework*

```
public function resize($w, $h) {

$image = Intervention::make($this)->fit($w, $h)->save($this->getPathname());
$filesize = filesize($this->getPathname());

    return new static(
        $this->getPathname(),
        $this->getClientOriginalName(),
        $this->getClientMimeType(),
        $filesize,
        null,
        false
    );
}
```

Using `Intervention`, I resized the image that is stored in the /tmp/ folder when files are uploaded and then I saved it in the same place. Now all I do after that is create an instance of UploadedFile so that I can keep using Laravel's methods on `request()->file('image')`. Hope this helps.